# error: Move target out of bounds. But I am pretty sure that I am not going out of an element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am getting this error when using Selenium Python:

Error Message: move target out of bounds
(Session info: chrome=121.0.6167.140)

However, I think that on my side, everything is working pretty well (I may be stupid and did not notice what I did wrong ofc)
Here's my script:

```
def click_on_coordinates(driver, canvas, coordinates):
   for pt in coordinates:
        try:
            actions = ActionChains(driver)

            print(pt)
            print(pt[0])
            print(pt[1])
            print(canvas.size)
            actions.move_to_element_with_offset(canvas, pt[0], pt[1])
            actions.perform()
            actions.reset_actions()

        except Exception as e:
            print('lala')
```

And here is my console:

```
(302, 254)
302
254
{'height': 963, 'width': 1920}
(236, 279)
236
279
{'height': 963, 'width': 1920}
(1730, 315)
1730
315
{'height': 963, 'width': 1920}
lala
```

So, the first and second coordinates worked, but not the third one, I do not understand why.
It may be because 1730>963 but I can't see how that could be the reason since 1730 is a width and 963 height.

Thanks!

```
                                                              .
```

Comment: The coordinates are relative to the onscreen center point of the element, not to the corner of the screen.

Comment: So, wherever the center of `canvas` is, you're trying to move an additional `(1730, 315)` beyond that point, which is out of range.